# My code caused the kernel to restart. Why is the kernel restarting?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, recursion, kernel

I wrote this `for` python code and got an unexpected output. The output was a number of zeros then it said "restarting kernel". Why is the kernel restarting?

```
def countdown(n):
    for n in range(0,5):
        print(n)
        countdown(n-1)
countdown(2)
```

On the other hand, I tried with `if` and there was no problem:

```
def countdown(n):
    if n == 0:
        print("blast of")
    else:
        print(n)
        countdown(n-1)
countdown(5)
```

So why is it not working with `for`?

Comment: You're not getting a recursion error?

Comment: Your function calls itself without limit. If you wanted a recursive function you need a base case to limit the stack usage.

Comment: Also, you're shadowing the `n` argument in the `for` loop.

Comment: Ok, contrary to my usual practise, I'm going to ask you to also post the `"I tried it with 'if'"` code so we can compare.

Comment: If you're running this as a Jupyter notebook, you might be missing the recursion error. Try writing the code in a regular `.py` file and you should see the actual error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
>    def countdown(n):
>        for n in range(0,5):
>            print(n)
>            countdown(n-1)
>    countdown(2)
```

In your code above, each function call will call itself recursively 5 times. So the first call is 5, second call there will be 25 calls, third call 125 calls, and the recursive calls went exponentially high, causing the Kernel to restart.

If you use recursive function, there *must* be an exit condition. There are a few ways to achieve your goal:

(1) recursive with if-condition exit (this is your successful code)

```
def countdown(n):
    if n == 0:
        print("blast off!")
    else:
        print(n)
        countdown(n-1)
countdown(5)
```

(2) recursive with while-condition exit

```
def countdown(n):
    while n != 0:
        print(n)
        countdown(n-1)
        return
    print("blast off!")
countdown(5)
```

(3) for loop (no need recursive)

```
def countdown(n):
    for i in range(n, 0, -1):
        print(i)
    print("blast off!")
countdown(5)
```

Output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
blast off!
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` recursive version is the correct form for recursion.

With a for loop you don't need a recursive function, just iterate from n to 0, and when you're done, print your blast off.

```py
def countdown(n):
    for in range(n,0,-1):
        print(n)
    else:
        print("blast off")
```

**NB.** I am using the `for/else` construct here, it means the `else` block with be executed when the `for` loop completes fully without `break`.

`countdown(5)` gives

```
5
4
3
2
1
blast off
```

Answer (score 1):

Code you posted:

```py
def countdown(n):
    if n == 0:
        print("blast of")
    else:
        print(n)
        countdown(n-1)
countdown(5)
```

This is a recursive function because it has a base case (`if n == 0:`).

This code has a loop built in due to the recursion: `countdown(n-1)`

If you want a `for` loop, then really you don't need recursion.

Comment: how do I do it for the for loop?

Comment: @ljmc answered with the `for` loop version.